# Can we use autoencoders to change an existing image instead of create one from scratch?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to think if we can use autoencoders to edit an existing image instead of saying, creating a new one from scratch.

To give an example, say I train my data on the MNIST dataset. If I now give my model a 9 and ask it to convert to an 8, would it be able to alter the pixels to create 8?

If yes, can you point me to some resources for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Autoencoders are typically used to reconstruct the input image, not to transpose one image into other.

You might want to look into GANs instead. check [blog post from machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-generative-adversarial-network-for-an-mnist-handwritten-digits-from-scratch-in-keras/)

Comment: Ah okay. I'll explain my problem in detail. I'm doing a project where I'm segmenting damaged vs not damaged property in flooded areas from satellite images. I want to do this thing where I give a satellite image of a not flooded area, and the model will do 2 things:

1. Image segmentation to differentiate roads from buildings etc.
2. Then make it seem like the roads are flooded.

I do not have experience working with GANs. Do you know of any resources I can work off of to this end?

Comment: sounds good. Resource pointed above from machine learning mastery is a good place to start.

Comment: Could you recommend some other resources for combining Image segmentation with GANs if you're aware?